# Mask area not visible in sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting, masking

I can add and manipulate a mask on an object while sculpting.  The mask behaves as if it is present, but the mask itself is not shown in the display area.  I would have expected the inactive region to be shown as dark or differently colored, but it doesn't display at all.  See below.

[image: Mask is present and active but not rendered]

As you can see on the left, there's no indication that there is a mask on the object, but when sculpted it behaves just like one is there.  How can I get the mask to display?  What are some reasons it might not be shown?

I can not find any of the masking options out of place.

Answer (score 6):

I can't write english well. So my answer is picture.

[image]

Comment: shame this topic was closed - the question seems pretty clear to me - I had the exact same problem for the longest while - in the end user42703's answer was the solution: if the mesh on which you are painting a sculpt mask has a modifier on it, the mask won't show up unless the modifier is disabled - the screencap from user42703 shows the warning that appears at bottom of the modifier stack when such a modifier/mask conflict occurs - with the offending modifier disabled masks appear properly in sculpt mode

Comment: In my case Subsurf was already disabled. However, it turned out that Armature modifier also disables mask display, but does not show any warning. So if mask is not visible, it may be necessary to disable other modifiers as well. I do not understand why this question was closed "as uncler" - it looks perfectly clear to me, and was first result when I googled "blender sculpting mask not visible".